# How to reload/rfresh a div on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div block i want it to be automatically referrshed once or  twice during when page is loading .

How can refresh/reload the div once or twice using jquery or javascript?

Comment: "Reload" a div block... ? Like re-get it's content via ajax ? What for ?

Comment: Can you give some more idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean but try to look this example

```
$(function () {

setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "Ajax/funk.cshtml",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#divId').text(data);
                    alert('Load completed.');
        }
    });
}, 2000);
});
```

here:
setInterval performs the action every 2000 milliseconds;
jax/funk.cshtml - the file which will give you some text as a result(it may contain only `@DateTime.Now` for example in asp.net and will return time)

if you want renew the div only once you may use the same function for `$(#somedive).onload();`
or something like that.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

Where is it gonna reload from, what does the block look like  ?

I would use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and reload content into the the div

but thats a much as I can say without having any idea about what the content is to look like , what the current content looks like or what you would receive back from an ajax call

hth