# Referesh DIV after pageload in Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

How can i refresh or reload the div using jquery ajax on page load

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277618/how-to-reload-rfresh-a-div-on-page-load

Comment: Try this `$.ready(function(){ $("#divId").load("your url" , function(){ alert ("div Loaded.");})})`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code. Actually it is done by using `$.load()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
 body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
 </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Footer navigation:</b>
<ol id="new-nav"></ol>

<script>
  $("#new-nav").load("/ #jq-footerNavigation li");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code helps to load the lower navigation of the default page in the Div

Check out this [Link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Where is #new-nav ID ? and i don't get anything from remote server i just want to reload div when page load

Comment: @PhpSeeker: that doesn't even make sense. What do you want to reload the `div` _with_ if not some content from the remote server? The example given in this answer basically does the following: it load the same page (i.e. `"/"`) again in the background, it extracts the contents of `"#jq-footerNavigation li"` from that page and it places the newly loaded content in `"#new-nav"`. You can replace all three of those variables to suit your needs.

Comment: @PhpSeeker Ya why do you really want to refresh the `div` when there is nothing out there. Or else the best solution is to replace the div's contents that you want to be replaced and then reinsert the `div`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).load(function() {
   $("#elementID").load('/path/to/remoteFile');
});
```